# ¿Cómo bloquear un <botón> cuando mi campo <input> está vacío?

Tags: javascript, html5

Soy nuevo en esto de HTML y JavaScript.
El problema es que cuando yo deje el campo input vacio, el boton debe bloquearse y no me deje hacer más acciones.
Este es el codigo:

El codigo de la caja de texto es el siguiente:

```
<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" value="1" />
```

El codigo del boton es el siguiente:

```
<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="btn_Validar" 
 class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart">Añadir al carrito
</button>
```

Pero en javascript no sé que codigo se debe poner. Me pueden orientar porfavor.

Comment: Encontre este link espero te pueda servir
[Disabling submit button until all fields have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la forma más fácil, validando en el evento `onInput` la longitud del valor del input y desactivándolo si no tiene al menos un caracter.

```js
function validarInput() {
  document.getElementById("btn_Validar").disabled = !document.getElementById("quanti").value.length;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" value="1" onInput="validarInput()" />

<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="btn_Validar" 
 class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart">Añadir al carrito
</button>
```

Comment: Tu evento no se disparará si se pega contenido usando el mouse......

Comment: me sirvió, funciona, gracias

Comment: @Javi, Arreglado

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz 

Comment: Ahora si ya funciona correctamente

Comment: Gracias @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: como quedaria el codigo con mas inputs?

Comment: pregunto lo mismo, como quedaria el código con más inputs?? @CarlosMuñoz

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir un evento al `<input>` que se dispare cada vez que se escriba en él, te dejo un ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<input id="valor" type="text">
<button id="submit">Enviar</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function el(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

el("valor").addEventListener("input",function() {
    if (!this.value.length) { //Si la longitud de la cadena de caracteres es 0 => falsa
        el("submit").disabled = true; //Deshabilitamos el botón
    } else { //Si no...
        el("submit").disabled = false; //Lo habilitamos
    }
});
```

Ó, simplificándolo un poquito más...

```
function el(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

el("valor").addEventListener("input",function() {
    el("submit").disabled = Boolean(this.value.length<=0);
});
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: Probaré su código

Comment: @Hermann recuerda que te puse un ejemplo con elementos HTML distintos a los tuyos, si lo pruebas con tus elementos acuérdate de cambiar las "id" de sus elementos correspondientes.

Answer (score -1):

Lo he hecho así y funciona:

```
$('#quanti').change(function(){ 
    //alert("el input cambio");
    if($(this).val()==0){ //si el input es cero
        $('#btn_Validar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else{ // si tiene un valor diferente a cero
        $('#btn_Validar').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
});
```