# ¿Cómo bloquear un <button> al momento de cargar la pagina?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este problema, al momento de cargar la página mi `input` está vacío pero no está bloqueado el botón. El botón solamente funciona cuando yo escribo en el `input`. Y mi problema es que no se código JavaScript ponerle, que al momento de cargar la página inmediatamente me verifique que el `input` esté vacío y bloquee el botón.

Aquí el código HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" 
    onInput="validarInput('<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>')"  
    onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)"
/>

<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>" 
    class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart" >Agregar al carrito</button>
```

Aquí el código JavaScript:

```
<!-- acepta solo numeros, funciona bien-->
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function soloNumeros(e) {
        var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||(key==8))
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript>
function validarInput(iden) {
    /*Funcion del botón, funciona bien, pero solo cuando yo escribo*/
        document.getElementById(iden).disabled = !document.getElementById("quanti").value.length;
    }
</script>
```

Ahora el problema es que como yo no se mucho de JavaScript no sé que código agregar para que al momento de cargar la página, bloquee el botón cuando el `input` esté vació. Por favor, ¿alguien tiene una idea de cómo agregar el script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente agrégale el atributo `disabled` (o `disabled="disabled"` si estas usando XHTML) al botón para que comienze desactivado.

```
<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" disabled id="<?php echo $row['idArticulo']; ?>" 
class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart" >Agregar al carrito</button>
```

No necesitas verificar que el input este vacío ya que siempre comenzará vacío (según el código que has mostrado)

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo usar Jquery, asi es mas facil: va comentado para mejor explicacion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control" >
<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" 
    class="btn btn-warning add_to_cart" >Agregar al carrito</button>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   //$(document).ready se ejecuta cuando carga la pagina
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);   //desactiva el input al cargar
     $('input[type="number"]').keyup(function() {   //cuando presionas tecla 
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que el botón aparezca desactivado puedes hacerlo desde el mismo html, poniendo el atributo [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> Este atributo booleano indica que el usuario no puede interactuar con
>   el botón. Si no se especifica este atributo, el botón hereda su
>   configuración del elemento que contiene, por ejemplo ; Si no
>   hay ningún elemento que contiene con el conjunto de atributos
>   deshabilitado, entonces el botón está habilitado.

Por ejemplo:

```
<button id="btnEnviar" disabled>Enviar</button>
```

Luego, por Javascript puedes escuchar el evento `keyup` para determinar si hay datos en el input y en consecuencia, activar o desactivar el botón.

Ejemplo:

```js
var btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnEnviar');
var inputTest = document.getElementById('inputTest');
var datos = inputTest.val;

inputTest.addEventListener("keyup",function(){

if(inputTest.value.length === 0){
    console.log('desactivado');
    btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  }

  else {  

    console.log('activado');
    btnEnviar.disabled = false;

    }
  });
```

```html
<label for="enviar">Escriba sus datos</label><input id="inputTest" type="text" ><button id="btnEnviar" disabled>Enviar</button>
```

Comment: La parte de activar o desactivar el botón ya está resuleto en esta pregunta: [¿Cómo bloquear un <botón> cuando mi campo <input> está vacío?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95679/c%C3%B3mo-bloquear-un-bot%C3%B3n-cuando-mi-campo-input-est%C3%A1-vac%C3%ADo)